# Authenticate the SmtpClient using AppID and APPSecret instead of passing the username and password

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, microsoft-graph, smtp

I have the following SharePoint CSOM code inside my c# console application to send an email using the office 365 admin username and password using the                     `client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, passWord);`, as follow :-

```
 static private void sendemail(ClientContext context, string subject, string body, FieldUserValue[] to, string username, SecureString passWord)
        {

            try
            {
                using (MailMessage mail = new MailMessage())
                {

                    mail.From = new MailAddress("sharepoint@***.com");
                    mail.Subject = subject;
                    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("***-com.mail.protection.outlook.com", 25);
                    client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                    client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, passWord);
                    client.EnableSsl = true;
                    mail.Body = body;
                    string approvalemailTo = "";

                    foreach (var t in to)
                    {
                        mail.To.Add(t.Email);
                        approvalemailTo = approvalemailTo + t.Email + ";";
                    }
                    client.Send(mail);
                    }
            }


            catch (Exception e)
            {

                   

            }

        }
```

but to make my code more secure, how i can authenticate the SmtpClient  using AppID and APPSecret instead of passing the username and password?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a SharePoint-related question as we're just talking about SMTP mail. With Exchange Online, you have a few [options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365#option-2-send-mail-directly-from-your-printer-or-application-to-microsoft-365-or-office-365-direct-send) you can evaluate; these will use username/password as SMTP relays are not compatible with OAuth. Option 2 or 3 should fit your needs.